# Bucket of sanitising fluid, kept for future use, is it effective, how long will it last?

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer

Whenever I sanitise ( with VWP ) I don't just chuck it away, I put it into a fermentation bucket outside my house. I stick all my bits n bobs - stainless beer paddle, syphon and bits in there, and leave them there until the next brew and I'll top it up with more sanitiser when I stick the next brew on.

Interested on any issues with this, but specifically may I ask your opinion if a stainless steel spoon left here for a week should only need a rinse before use - rinse again after stirring return to sanitising bucket?

Comment: Assuming your rinse is just tap water, it is kind of defeating the purpose of sanitizing to rinse before use. Typically, most people wash after use and sanitize before use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never worked with VWP.  But it appears to be a chlorine based agent.  Chlorine based agents lose their potency quickly after dilution (regardless of solution clarity or pH).

In general, there is no added advantage to keep your brewing hardware in a solution until the next brew cycle.  I'd recommend making a fresh solution each brew day.  If you haven't had any problems well then good for you and you can ignore this.  But whenever I leave stuff sitting in either cleansers or my sanitizer it gets a little slimy and weird.  I prefer to clean at brews end and sanitize before the next session.

Furthermore, looking at the few references to it online it says cleanser/steriliser on the label.  Its very difficult for any product to do both.  By U.S. standards I doubt it is even remotely a steriliser.  Sanitizer maybe but not a sterilizer.

Answer (score -1):

The rule of thumb is as long as the Sanitizer is clear and not cloudy you will be fine. A rinse of the spoon should be fine.